# Adding Delete button to a data binding ListView

Tags: android, listview

I've created a `ListView` and bind it to an adaptor to display data from a table. It works great.  I can select on a row and it display the product name that I'm selecting.  Now I've added an `ImageView` in the layout that will act as delete buttons on each row.  My problem is I can't figure out how to add the code to make it so that when a user select the `ImageView` (delete button), it will delete the row.  I've searched and found a lot of articles on this topic and tried a lot of them and none really work my code.  Do I need to create a `getView` function?  Also I've tried inserting the `getTag()`, but I couldn't make it work.  Can you help me with a sample code that may work with my simple code or point me to the right direction?    Here is my code:

```
private void displayListView() {       
    prodinputHelper = new DBAdaptorProductInput(this);   
    prodinputHelper.open();     
    Cursor cursor = prodinputHelper.fetchAllProductInput();     
    // The desired columns to be bound   
    String[] columns = new String[] {     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_PRODUCTTYPE,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_PRODUCTNAME,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_MANUFACTURER,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_VISC40,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_VISC100,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_VI,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_DEN15C,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_VISCTEXT,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_BASEOILTYPE,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_BASEOIL,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_ADDITIVES,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_OTHERADDITIVES,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_THICKENER,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_NLGI,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_COMMENT,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_PACKAGES,     
            DBAdaptorProductInput.KEY_AREA,     
    };     
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to   
    int[] to = new int[] {      
            R.id.code,     
            R.id.name,     
            R.id.manufacturer,     
            R.id.visc40,     
            R.id.visc100,     
            R.id.viscindex,     
            R.id.den15c,     
            R.id.visctext,     
            R.id.baseoiltype,     
            R.id.baseoil,     
            R.id.additives,     
            R.id.otheradditives,     
            R.id.thickener,     
            R.id.nlgi,     
            R.id.comments,     
            R.id.packages,     
            R.id.area,     
    };     
    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data    
    //as well as the layout information   
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(     
            this, R.layout.activity_product_review_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);     

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);   
    // Assign adapter to ListView   
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter); 

    //SetOnItemClickListener for the ListView
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
    @Override   
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,       
            int position, long id) {    

        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set    
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);      
        // Get the Customer Name from this row in the database.    
        String countryCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ProductName"));    

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

        }   

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
In the adapter's `getView()` method set the `onClickListener` for your `ImageView`.